# Query Builder usando Laravel y dos bases de datos distintas

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5, sql, querybuilder

vengo en esta oportunidad con un problemilla gordo.

Quiero fabricar un query usando query builder, pero necesito meter dos bases de datos en la consulta.

Les muestro el query en SQL:

```
SELECT
naviones_db16.ps_orders.payment,
naviones_db16.ps_orders.total_paid AS total,
naviones_db16.ps_orders.current_state AS current_state,
naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_order AS id_order,
naviones_db16.ps_shop.NAME AS name_shop,
naviones_db16.ps_customer.firstname AS customer_firstname,
naviones_db16.ps_customer.lastname AS customer_lastname,
naviones_db16.ps_orders.reference,
naviones_db16.ps_orders.date_add AS fecha
FROM
ps_orders
INNER JOIN naviones_db16.ps_customer ON 
 naviones_db16.ps_customer.id_customer= 
 naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_customer
 INNER JOIN naviones_db16.ps_shop ON naviones_db16.ps_shop.id_shop = 
 naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_shop
 WHERE
 naviones_db16.ps_orders.current_state = 16
 AND 
 naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_order NOT IN (
 SELECT
    multimarket.productos.id_order
FROM
    multimarket.productos
WHERE
    multimarket.productos.id_order = naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_order
)
 ORDER BY
   naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_order DESC
```

Esto es lo que yo tenia hecho en query builder

```
$naviones = DB::connection('naviones')->table('ps_orders')
        ->select('ps_orders.payment', 'ps_orders.total_paid AS total', 'ps_orders.current_state AS current_state', 'ps_orders.id_order AS id_order',
            'ps_shop.NAME AS name_shop', 'ps_customer.firstname AS customer_firstname', 'ps_customer.lastname AS customer_lastname', 'ps_orders.reference',
            'ps_orders.date_add AS fecha')
        ->join('ps_customer', 'ps_customer.id_customer', '=', 'ps_orders.id_customer')
        ->join('ps_shop', 'ps_shop.id_shop', '=', 'ps_orders.id_shop')
        ->where('ps_orders.current_state', '=', '16')
        ->orderBy('id_order', 'DESC')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

Claro tengo otra conexion que seria: DB::connections('multimarket') pero es lo que no tengo idea de como incorporar en query builder, me podeis dar alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: has intentado usando eloquent o solo puedes usar querybuilder?

Comment: Como solo necesito acceder a una base de datos de prestashop no veo necesario crear modelos de eloquent por eso estoy usando query builder.

Comment: Porque con eloquent puede decirle a cada modelo con que conexion va a trabajar te puedo colocar un ejemplo en la respuesta si te sirve de ese modo

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, eso lo se, pero no puedo trabajar con modelos, debe ser con query builder.

Comment: No sé si vaya a funcionar, pero puedes probar con una sintaxis así `DB::table('naviones_db16.ps_orders') ->join('multimarket.productos, 'multimarket.productos.id_order, '=', 'naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_order) ->select('naviones_db16.ps_orders.id_order AS db16_id_order', 'multimarket.productos.*') ->get();`